# How to guess the least number of spheres in a problem involving taking out objects from a jar?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> A porcelain jar has inside $20$ spheres labeled with integer numbers
>   from $1$ to $20$. How many spheres at least do it has to be taken out
>   of the jar randomly to be certain that the sum of two of them is a
>   prime number less than $20$?

This situation I also found lost during exams as I don't know where to begin.
I sketched the situation as this:

The spheres are labeled from $1$ to $20$

$1,2,3,4....20$

and they are asking the sum is prime so, to have the least number or spheres I can consider the worst case scenario which would mean that each time I take out a sphere I will get a non prime number so their sum is also a non prime.

The non prime numbers in that range are

$4,6,9,10,12,14,15,16,18,20$

So the least number is $10$?

I feel that the answer is incomplete or not correct. Can somebody help me to solve this situation in a more logical way without guessing?

I'd like to learn what is it behind this probability question. Am I on the right track.

What can I conclude to get a prime number, the sum of two primes is also a prime (seems logical, but is it true?). The sum of two non primes is a non prime also logical, but can I conclude that?.

I need help to clear these ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You are asked for the number you need to draw to make sure the sum of two of them is a prime less than $20$, but answered the number you need to draw to make sure you get a single sphere that is a prime less than $20$.  For the question you answered, you missed that $1$ is not prime and you need to draw one more to be the prime, so you need to draw $12$.

For drawing numbers such that there is not a pair that sums to a prime less than $20$, you want all the big numbers you can get.  You can draw $20$ and $19$ without fear that you will get a prime less than $20$.  In fact you can draw $10$ through $20$ without getting a sum less than $20$, let alone a prime.  Having done that, any number you draw will let you get a sum of $19$, so you need to draw at least $12$ balls.  This is not a proof that $12$ is the answer, but it is a lower bound.

To prove that $12$ is an upper bound, pair up $n$ and $19-n$ for $n \in [1,9]$.  There are nine pairs here, each summing to $19$, so you can only pull one of each pair and avoid two numbers summing to a prime less than $20$.  You can add $19$ and $20$ to make $11$ numbers as the maximum you can have without having a sum of $19$, so drawing $12$ numbers guarantees there is a pair summing to a prime less than $20$.

Comment: Can we rewind just a bit, as I'm getting a bit lost reading at you. I'm not very familiar with this. So step one is take out all numbers between $20-10$ so that would be $10$ numbers. Where are those other two?. The next ball can be let's say $1$ and that is not prime, then we're at $11$ so um... where's the missing one?. It can be any between $2$ to $9$, Adding $1$ to $9$ renders $10$ and that is not prime, so I need to take other and we're at $12$, So the remaining $2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10$, but I can continue taking out balls, $2$ and $4$ make out $6$ and that's not prime.

Comment: So far I'm at $14$ as taken out $2$ and $4$. But if I keep following this route I'll end up extracting all the balls. Where did I get lost?. The part where I pair up with $19-n$ is that an identity I'm missing?.

Comment: No, taking out $20$ through $10$ is $11$ numbers.  You have a fencepost error.  At this point you don't have two to sum to a prime, so need to take out one more to have two that sum to a prime.  Now for any number you draw, you can find a number in the range $10-20$ that will sum with it to $19$.  For example, if you draw $2$ you pair it with $17$ and have a sum of $19$

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes I was off by one, it also has to be noted that I have to consider the spheres I already taken out. It just happens that the max value $19$ is also a prime. So, I don't have to worry about making a sum that is prime, just taking out numbers and use that fact in the end. Is this what you meant?.

Comment: I don't understand the comment.  The max value is $20$, which is not prime.  We need two things, one of which I did in each of the last two paragraphs.  We need to show how to draw $11$ spheres without making a prime sum, which shows that you need to draw at least $12$.  Then we have to prove that for any $12$ you draw you can make a prime sum.  In this case we can prove that for any $12$ you draw you can make $19$, but in other cases we couldn't guarantee any particular sum.  We could just guarantee a prime sum

Comment: Ross what I was trying to say is that for someone who is not very familiar with solving this problems or has not practiced much with them would be tempted to focus its attention into trying to find out the pairs which make a prime number therefore  getting tangled up with several trials hence losing valuable time in an exam. I said maximum is $19$ as this is the maximum sum that has to be achieved as the problem says, not the maximum value written on the balls. From your method I understood that the thing is not get "scared" about trying to figure out the pairs first.

Comment: Only just begin to take out all the numbers which its sum is out of the range and this simplifies the problem, but when we're doing this we already have numbers at our disposal that can be later be used to achieve a prime sum within the range. This latter part I mentioned was the key into understanding my doubts. Initially I was confused on how do I know that to prove $12$ is an upper bound I have to pair $n$ and $19-n$.

Comment: But after a deeper thought I realized that we choose this value as it is the maximum prime below $20$, so I want to know which pairs do make that and as you said there are $9$. By the time I have $10$ any number from $1$ to $9$ will make the sum fall in that range. I tried with $1$ and was confused I need $18$, where is it? and it was the ball which I already have extracted from the jar. Now, this is not part of the problem, but would this $12$ also work to answer the question if it has asked to find an even number below $20$?.

Comment: No, if you are looking for an even number below $20$ you can draw all the balls $9$ through $20$ without making one, so you have to draw $13$ to make one.  For making an even number $20$ or below I believe the answer is $12$

Answer (score 0):

It appears the solution we want is the least number of draws to be absolutely certain that we have any two spheres that add up to a prime number. And also, note that we can have two non primes add up to a prime number, for example $9+8=17$

Also see that two primes can be added together to make a non prime, like $13+3=16$

To figure out this problem, we need to look at the different possible combinations of spheres and see if every possible combination of a certain size $k$ contains two numbers that add up to a prime less than $20$. And any time we can find a combination of size $k$ that doesn't fit the criteria, then we go up to the next size $k+1$.

For example, see that we definitely need  to pick more than $3$ spheres if we want to guarantee we follow the criteria because if we picked the combination $\{3,5,7\}$  we can't take any two of those numbers and add them up to a prime number less than $20$.

A computer program of some sort may be needed to successfully solve this problem as writing out all the possible combinations by hand would be tedious. We can confirm that the number of spheres picked definitely needs to be more than $3$ (as shown above) and of course it can't be over $20$.

Ross Millikan gives a great answer as well (+1 to that) but I hope both of our answers together helps you understand the problem better